# error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this error.. I have tried everything I could think of and have looked at a number of examples on the web. But I'm still stuck!

Thanks

error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression

```
unsigned char mbuffer[16];

int bcd_encode(32768UL, &mbuffer[0], 4);   <---- error is on this line



-------------------------------------------------

/* Encode the input number into BCD into the output buffer, of
 * the specified length.  The BCD encoded number is right-justified
 * in the field.  Return the number of digits converted, or -1 if the
 * buffer was not big enough for the whole conversion.
 */
int bcd_encode(unsigned long number, unsigned char *cbuffer, int length)
{
  unsigned char *p;
  unsigned char n, m, bval, digit;

   n = 0;     /* nibble count */
   m = 0;     /* converted digit count */
   bval = 0;  /* the bcd encoded value */


   /* Start from the righthand end of the buffer and work
    * backwards
    */
   p = cbuffer + length - 1;
   while (p >= cbuffer) {

       if (number != 0) {
          digit = number % 10;
          number = number / 10;
          m++;
       } else
          digit = 0;

       /* If we have an odd-numbered digit position
        * then save the byte and move to the next buffer
        * position.  Otherwise go convert another digit
        */
       if (n & 1) {
          bval |= digit << 4;
          *p-- = bval;
          bval = 0;
       } else
          bval = digit;

       n++;
   }

   /* If number is not zero, then we have run out of room
    * and the conversion didn't fit.  Return -1;
    */
   if (number)
      return(-1);

   /* return the number of converted digits
    */
   return(m);
}
```

Comment: Is the line with the error inside a function or not? Is it meant to be a function prototype, or a function call? Explain what you think the line with the error should do.

Answer (score 1):

Why are there values in the function prototype?

Should be:

```
int bcd_encode(unsigned long number, unsigned char *cbuffer, int length);
```

Or if you're trying to make a call to that function, do as unwind said and remove the int from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You're having a lonely `int` before the call, that's not valid.

It should be:

```
const int numDigits = bcd_encode(32768UL, &mbuffer[0], 4);
```